# How to restore variables using CheckpointReader in Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to restore some variables from checkpoint file if same variable name is in current model.
And I found that there is some way as in [Tensorfow Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8df836f2611c533c54d2bdaaf107c67afac8d6a5/tensorflow/python/training/saver_test.py#L1214)

So what I want to do is checking variable names in checkpoint file using `has_tensor("variable.name")` as below,

```
...    
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(ckpt_path)
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    print v.name
    if reader.has_tensor(v.name):
        print 'has tensor'
...
```

But I found that `v.name` returns both variable `name` and `colon+number`. For example, I have variable name `W_o` and `b_o` then `v.name` returns `W_o:0, b_o:0`.

However `reader.has_tensor()` requires `name` without `colon` and `number` as `W_o, b_o`.

My question is: how to remove the `colon` and `number` at the end of the variable name in order to read the variables?
Is there a better way to restore such variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [string.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) to get the tensor name:

```
...    
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(ckpt_path)
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    tensor_name = v.name.split(':')[0]
    print tensor_name
    if reader.has_tensor(tensor_name):
        print 'has tensor'
...
```

Next, let me use an example to show how I would restore every possible variable from a `.cpkt` file. First, let's save `v2` and `v3` in `tmp.ckpt`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

v1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]), name='v1')
v2 = tf.Variable(2 * tf.ones([1]), name='v2')
v3 = tf.Variable(3 * tf.ones([1]), name='v3')

saver = tf.train.Saver({'v2': v2, 'v3': v3})

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    saver.save(sess, 'tmp.ckpt')
```

That's how I would restore every variable (belonging to a new graph) showing up in  `tmp.ckpt`:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    assert len(tf.trainable_variables()) == 0
    v1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='v1')
    v2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name='v2')

    reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader('tmp.ckpt')
    restore_dict = dict()
    for v in tf.trainable_variables():
        tensor_name = v.name.split(':')[0]
        if reader.has_tensor(tensor_name):
            print('has tensor ', tensor_name)
            restore_dict[tensor_name] = v

    saver = tf.train.Saver(restore_dict)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        saver.restore(sess, 'tmp.ckpt')
        print(sess.run([v1, v2])) # prints [array([ 0.], dtype=float32), array([ 2.], dtype=float32)]
```

Also, you may want to ensure that shapes and dtypes match.

Comment: Thanks rvinas!! I think it is the most clear example how to restore desired variables among what I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

tf.train.NewCheckpointReader is a nifty method that creates a CheckpointReader object. CheckpointReader has several very useful methods. The method that would be the most relevant to your question would be get_variable_to_shape_map().

- get_variable_to_shape_map() provides a dictionary with variable names and shapes:

```js
saved_shapes = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
print 'fire9/squeeze1x1/kernels:', saved_shapes['fire9/squeeze1x1/kernels']
```

Please take a look at this quick tutorial below:
[Loading Variables from Existing Checkpoints](https://github.com/aponamarev/TF_Object_Det/blob/master/LoadVar_from_exisitng_checkpoint.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check your tutorial and try your method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader(checkpoint_file)

variable1 = reader.get_tensor('layer_name1/layer_type_name')
variable2 = reader.get_tensor('layer_name2/layer_type_name')
```

Now, after modification to these variables, you can assign it back.

```
layer_name1_var.set_weights([variable1, variable2])
```