# SELECTIVELY Restore Weights in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have two neural network (TF Computation Graph) defined like following:

1. Model 1: some input&hidden layers + a 3-way softmax layer
2. Model 2: some input&hidden layers(same as Model 1) + a binary Sigmoid layer

The only difference between Model 1 and 2 is the output layer.

I have stored some trained parameters for Model 1 and would like to use them (the input & hidden layers) to initialize new Model 2. Ideally, for Model 2, the input & hidden layers should use the saved weights while the output layer will be randomly initialized. I am wondering if it is possible to implement this partial weights recovery in TensorFlow. What is the best practice to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: To pass a list of variables to the restore method

Comment: Saver constructor allows you to specify list of variables in its `__init__`

Comment: Check out the section "Choosing which Variables to Save and Restore" at https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/

Comment: Also, if you have different names for the variables in the output layer, you may find comfortable to use a Checkpoint Reader as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137597/how-to-restore-variables-using-checkpointreader-in-tensorflow/39142780

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I passed in a var_list in saver constructor. This allows me to selectively recover weights.