# Can Tensorflow Saver restore model adaptively?

Tags: tensorflow

I have saved a TF model with `tf.train.Saver` and next time I will modify my original model like adding new layer or keeping some layer untrainable. But when I restore the old model, I get an error that some key was not found in `checkpoint`. Somebody have told me that I can maintain a `var_list` to store the variables I want to restore and restore the model partially. But in practice this is not easy as there are so many variables, including weights, biases and some variables from optimizer or batch normalization.  Is there some way to make it more convenient? Or can TF automatically restore the model partially, by deciding whether the variable's name can be found in model file? If so such key is found, it can just initialize the variable.

Comment: Please give a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model. There it is well described how you need to do it.

Comment: Please check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137597/how-to-restore-variables-using-checkpointreader-in-tensorflow/39142780#39142780